# How to activate the Ctrl+F research shortcut into an Electron application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, chromium

I can't use the **Ctrl+F** shorcut to research some text into my Electron application...

Please see below the best part of the `main.js` file :

```
/*App*/

app.on("ready", () => {
  createWindow();
});

app.on("activate", function() {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

app.on("window-all-closed", function() {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});

/*Windows*/

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1800,
    height: 960,
    minWidth: 1190,
    minHeight: 540,
    icon: iconPath,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      nativeWindowOpen: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile("dist-ng/index.html");

  mainWindow.on("minimize", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mainWindow.hide();
  });

  mainWindow.on("close", function(event) {
    if (!app.isQuiting) {
      event.preventDefault();
      mainWindow.hide();
    }
    return false;
  });
```

I think there's some configuration to add to enable the **Ctrl+F** shorcut but I can't find it with the Electron documentation...

Please could you help me ?